# WebView and error management, what's wrong?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, error-handling, webview, connectivity

I'm working on a **Xamarin.Forms app** where I need to integrate a `WebView` to manage **booking through an external URL**.

So basically I've did this in my view:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Source="{Binding BookingUrl}"
         WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000">
```

I would like to manage **some errors** that the users could encounter while opening this page: no internet access, timeout, unavailable server,...

For this I've used `EventToCommandBehavior`to acess to the events `Navigating` and `Navigating` in the **ViewModel**.

So my **XAML** looks like this:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Source="{Binding AvilaUrlBooking}"
            WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000">
    <WebView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="Navigating"
            Command="{Binding NavigatingCommand}" />
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="Navigated"
            Command="{Binding NavigatedCommand}" />
    </WebView.Behaviors>
</WebView>
```

And the **ViewModel** is like this:

```
public ICommand NavigatingCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Xamarin.Forms.Command<WebNavigatingEventArgs>(async (x) =>
        {
            if (x != null)
            {
                await WebViewNavigatingAsync(x);
            }
        });
    }
}

private Task WebViewNavigatingAsync(WebNavigatingEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (!IsConnected)
        ServiceErrorKind = ServiceErrorKind.NoInternetAccess;

    IsBusy = true;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public ICommand NavigatedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Xamarin.Forms.Command<WebNavigatedEventArgs>(async (x) =>
        {
            if (x != null)
            {
                await WebViewNavigatedAsync(x);
            }
        });
    }
}

private Task WebViewNavigatedAsync(WebNavigatedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    IsBusy = false;
    IsFirstDisplay = false;
    switch (eventArgs.Result)
    {
        case WebNavigationResult.Cancel:
            // TODO - do stuff here
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Failure:
            // TODO - do stuff here
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Success:
            // TODO - do stuff here
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Timeout:
            // TODO - do stuff here
            break;
        default:
            // TODO - do stuff here
            break;
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

bool isFirstDisplay;
public bool IsFirstDisplay
{
    get { return isFirstDisplay; }
    set { SetProperty(ref isFirstDisplay, value); }
}

public BookingViewModel()
{
    _eventTracker = new AppCenterEventTracker();
    IsFirstDisplay = true;
    Title = "Booking";

    IsConnected = Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet;
    Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += OnConnectivityChanged;
}
```

If I use the right URL, all works fine on iOS and Android.

However, if I use a "wrong" URL (with missing char for example), this is only working on **Android**: the case `WebNavigationResult.Failure` is catched in `WebViewNavigatedAsync()`, but I don't enter in `WebViewNavigatedAsync()` on **iOS**.

***=> is this normal?***

I've implemented a **"Refresh" button** to manage the "**No Internet access**" error. This button is accessible through a `ToolBarItem`, it's like this in the **ViewModel**:

```
public void Refresh(object sender)
{
    try
    {
        var view = sender as Xamarin.Forms.WebView;
        view.Reload();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

But in these case too, I have 2 different behaviours after having activated the Airplane mode:

- on **iOS**, when there is no internet access: I don't enter in `WebViewNavigatedAsync()`, even if the internet access is available again and I click on the **"Refresh" button**, I only pass by the `WebViewNavigatingAsync()`
- on **Android**, when there is no internet access: I well enter in `WebViewNavigatedAsync()`, and when the internet access is available again and I click on the **"Refresh" button**, I pass both by the `WebViewNavigatingAsync()` and `WebViewNavigatedAsync()`

***=> is this normal? Is there a proper way to manager this?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another approach that seems to work, based on the following links:
[image: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99790/xamarin-forms-custom-webviews-navigating-and-navigated-event-doesnt-raise-on-ios]

[image: https://gist.github.com/mrdaneeyul/9cedb3d972744de4f8752cb09024da42]

It's probably not perfect, especially as I need access to the required Events from the ViewModel.

So I've created a `CustomWebView` control that inherits from `WebView`:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }

    public CustomWebViewErrorKind ErrorKind { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler LoadingStart;
    public event EventHandler LoadingFinished;
    public event EventHandler LoadingFailed;

    /// <summary>
    /// The event handler for refreshing the page
    /// </summary>
    public EventHandler OnRefresh { get; set; }

    public void InvokeCompleted()
    {
        if (this.LoadingFinished != null)
        {
            ErrorKind = WebViewErrorKind.None;
            this.LoadingFinished.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }

    public void InvokeStarted()
    {
        if (this.LoadingStart != null)
        {
            ErrorKind = WebViewErrorKind.None;
            this.LoadingStart.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }

    public void InvokeFailed(CustomWebViewErrorKind errorKind)
    {
        if (this.LoadingFailed != null)
        {
            ErrorKind = errorKind;
            this.LoadingFailed.Invoke(this, null);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refreshes the current page
    /// </summary>
    public void Refresh()
    {
        OnRefresh?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Then I've the `CustomWkWebViewRenderer` that customizes the behavior of the `CustomWebView`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWkWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomWkWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, WKWebView>
    {

        public CustomWkWebViewRenderer()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"CustomWkWebViewRenderer - Ctor");
        }

        WKWebView webView;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Debug.WriteLine($"CustomWkWebViewRenderer - OnElementChanged()");

            if (Control == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"CustomWkWebViewRenderer - OnElementChanged() - Control == null");
                webView = new WKWebView(Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration()
                {
                    MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
                });
                webView.NavigationDelegate = new DisplayWebViewDelegate(Element);
                SetNativeControl(webView);

                Element.OnRefresh += (sender, ea) => Refresh(sender);
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"CustomWkWebViewRenderer - OnElementChanged() - e.NewElement != null");
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Uri)));
                webView.NavigationDelegate = new DisplayWebViewDelegate(Element);
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }
        }

        private void Refresh(object sender)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"CustomWkWebViewRenderer - Refresh()");
            Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Uri)));
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the `CustomWkWebViewNavigationDelegate` that implements the `WKNavigationDelegate` for this renderer:

```
    public class CustomWkWebViewNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
        private CustomWebView element;

        public CustomWkWebViewNavigationDelegate(CustomWebView element)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"CustomWkWebViewNavigationDelegate - Ctor");
            this.element = element;
        }

        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"CustomWkWebViewNavigationDelegate - DidFinishNavigation");
            element.InvokeCompleted();
            //base.DidFinishNavigation(webView, navigation);
        }

        public override void DidStartProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"CustomWkWebViewNavigationDelegate - DidStartProvisionalNavigation");
            element.InvokeStarted();
            //base.DidStartProvisionalNavigation(webView, navigation);
        }

        [Export("webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation:withError:")]
        public override void DidFailProvisionalNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation, NSError error)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"CustomWkWebViewNavigationDelegate - DidFailProvisionalNavigation - error : {error}");
            var errorKind = CustomWebViewErrorKind.None;
            switch (error.Code)
            {
                case -1009: // no internet access
                    {
                        errorKind = CustomWebViewErrorKind.NoInternetAccess;
                        break;
                    }
                case -1001: // timeout
                    {
                        errorKind = CustomWebViewErrorKind.Timeout;
                        break;
                    }
                case -1003: // server cannot be found
                case -1100: // url not found on server
                default:
                    {
                        errorKind = CustomWebViewErrorKind.Failure;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            element.InvokeFailed(errorKind);
            //base.DidFailProvisionalNavigation(webView, navigation, error);
        }
    }
```

There is a `CustomWebViewErrorKind` enum that will allow me to implement a common error management in the ViewModel:

```
public enum CustomWebViewErrorKind
{
    None = 0,
    NoInternetAccess = 1,
    Failure = 2,
    Timeout = 3,
    Cancel = 8,
    Other = 9
}
```

To access to the Events from the ViewModel, I use a `EventToCommandBehavior` like described [there](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior)

So, I've exposed all the Commands from the View like this:

```
<controls:CustomWebView x:Name="webView"
                        Source="{Binding MyUrlBooking}"
                        Uri="{Binding MyUrlBooking}"
                        WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000">
    <WebView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="Navigating"
            Command="{Binding NavigatingCommand}" />
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="Navigated"
            Command="{Binding NavigatedCommand}" />
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="LoadingStart"
            Command="{Binding LoadingStartCommand}" />
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="LoadingFinished"
            Command="{Binding LoadingFinishedCommand}" />
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="LoadingFailed"
            Command="{Binding LoadingFailedCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{x:Reference webView}"
            />
    </WebView.Behaviors>
</controls:CustomWebView>
```

And finally, in my ViewModel I do this for the Android part:

```
public ICommand NavigatingCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Xamarin.Forms.Command<WebNavigatingEventArgs>(async (x) =>
        {
            if (x != null)
            {
                await WebViewNavigatingAsync(x);
            }
        });
    }
}

private Task WebViewNavigatingAsync(WebNavigatingEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewNavigatingAsync()");

    IsBusy = true;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public ICommand NavigatedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Xamarin.Forms.Command<WebNavigatedEventArgs>(async (x) =>
        {
            if (x != null)
            {
                await WebViewNavigatedAsync(x);
            }
        });
    }
}

private Task WebViewNavigatedAsync(WebNavigatedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewNavigatedAsync()");

    IsBusy = false;
    switch (eventArgs.Result)
    {
        case WebNavigationResult.Cancel:
            Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewNavigatedAsync() - Cancel");
            ErrorKind = CustomWebViewErrorKind.Cancel;
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Failure:
        default:
            Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewNavigatedAsync() - Failure");
            IsConnected = Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet;
            if (IsConnected)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewNavigatedAsync() - Failure : Failure");
                ErrorKind = CustomWebViewErrorKind.Failure;
            }
            else
            if (IsConnected)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewNavigatedAsync() - Failure : NoInternetAccess");
                ErrorKind = CustomWebViewErrorKind.NoInternetAccess;
            }
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Success:
            Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewNavigatedAsync() - Success");
            ErrorKind = CustomWebViewErrorKind.None;
            IsFirstDisplay = false;
            break;
        case WebNavigationResult.Timeout:
            Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewNavigatedAsync() - Timeout");
            ErrorKind = CustomWebViewErrorKind.Timeout;
            break;
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And I do this for the iOS part:

```
public ICommand LoadingStartCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Xamarin.Forms.Command(async () =>
        {
            await WebViewLoadingStartAsync();
        });
    }
}

private Task WebViewLoadingStartAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewLoadingStartAsync()");
    IsBusy = true;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public ICommand LoadingFinishedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Xamarin.Forms.Command(async () =>
        {
            await WebViewLoadingFinishedAsync();
        });
    }
}

private Task WebViewLoadingFinishedAsync()
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewLoadingFinishedAsync()");
    IsBusy = false;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public ICommand LoadingFailedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Xamarin.Forms.Command<object>(async (object sender) =>
        {
            if (sender != null)
            {
                await WebViewLoadingFailedAsync(sender);
            }
        });
    }
}

private Task WebViewLoadingFailedAsync(object sender)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewLoadingFailedAsync()");
    var view = sender as CustomWebView;
    var error = view.ErrorKind;
    Debug.WriteLine($"BookingViewModel - WebViewLoadingFailedAsync() - error : {error}");
    IsBusy = false;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Like this I'm able to manage errors, retry and refresh from the ViewModel, even if it's probably not the better solution...

Answer (score 1):

> is this normal?

Based on my test. Yes, I got the same result, if we input an error url, the webview always be white-empty view in iOS. so the `NavigatedCommand` cannot be executed.

If we use correct url, the webview could excute the `NavigatedCommand`, and running result like following screenshot.

[image]

> Is there a proper way to manager this?

We can use custom renderer for webview in iOS to handle this situation.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyCarsourlView.iOS
{
    [Obsolete]
    class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null) { Delegate = new CustomWebViewDelegate(); }
        }
    }
}

internal class CustomWebViewDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate
{

    #region Event Handlers

    public override bool ShouldStartLoad(UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType)
    {

        //Could add stuff here to redirect the user before the page loads, if you wanted to redirect the user you would do the redirection and then return false

        return true;
    }

    public override void LoadFailed(UIWebView webView, NSError error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nIn AppName.iOS.CustomWebViewRenderer - Error: {0}\n", error.ToString());   //TODO: Do something more useful here
        //Here, you can test to see what kind of error you are getting and act accordingly, either by showing an alert or rendering your own custom error page using basic HTML
    }

    public override void LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)
    { //You could do stuff here such as collection cookies form the WebView }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

If I input wrong url, `LoadFailed` could be executed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Leon Lu - MSFT
Is it possible to manage other errors too? (timeout, incorrect response status, ...)
That also mean that I have to display the error pop-in from the Renderer? And there is probably no way to display an Error View with a "Retry" button in this case...

Comment: @Gold.strike navtive IOS could handle following errors.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nserror?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a common iOS/Android code in the ViewModel, to identify the errors (wrong URL, timeout, no internet, ...) and to manage them (full screen error view with a "Retry" button, pop in)  by firing the `WebView.Nagitated` event as soon as an error  has been catched in` LoadFailed()`?

Comment: You can use MessageCenter to notify the webview load error, You can send Message In the `LoadFailed()`, then subscribe the message in the PCL.